# VB.net Sort Arraylist By Objects Name

Tags: vb.net, sorting, arraylist

Trying to sort a arraylist by Objects name

```
Dim ObjList as new arraylist
Dim TextBox1 as new textbox
Textbox1.name = "CCC"
Dim TextBox2 as new textbox
Textbox1.name = "AAA"
Dim TextBox3 as new textbox
Textbox1.name = "BBB"
ObjList.add(TextBox1)
ObjList.add(TextBox2)
ObjList.add(TextBox3)
ObjList.sort()
```

Sort creates a error. How would I sort the TextBoxs by Name so it looks like
AAA
BBB
CCC

Thank you

Comment: You've set Textbox1.Name three times - in case that is actually what you meant I have left it to you to edit your post. Also, what version of Visual Studio are you using.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to create an [`IComparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer.aspx) and pass it to the [`Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0e743hdt.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) method:

```
Class TextBoxComparer 
    Implements IComparer

    Public Function Compare(x As Object, y As Object) As Integer Implements IComparer.Compare
        Return String.Compare(x.Name, y.Name)
    End Function

End Class

...

ObjList.Sort(New TextBoxComparer())
```

---

Or, if you can switch to [`List(Of TextBox)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx), an anonymous function (that matches the [Comparison(Of T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh.aspx) delegate) will also do:

```
Dim ObjList As New List(Of TextBox)

...

ObjList.Sort(Function(x, y) String.Compare(x.Name, y.Name))
```