# Can an ArrayList of objects be sorted by a custom method in VBScript?

Tags: sorting, arraylist, vbscript

First off - the language I'm using is VBScript, used with Windows Scripting Host.  I don't really have the option of changing that and using something else.

At this point, I have a number of records with multiple fields, read in from a file.  I want to print them out in a number of orderings (first, in alphabetical order; second, grouped by location and then sorted alphabetically within locations; etc.).  The records are stored in an ArrayList.

If I was using Visual Basic rather than VBScript, I know that I could create classes which implemented the iComparer interface, and then call the Sort function of the ArrayList with an object of the appropriate class when I wanted to sort in that order (use the Alphabetical object for the first sort, the LocationThenAlphabetical object for the second sort, etc.)

However, I have been going crazy trying to find a way to do that or anything similar in VBScript, the language I actually have available to work with.  I've Googled endless combinations of "VBScript", "ArrayList", "sort", "custom sort", "comparison", "custom comparison", "implements", "interface" - but whenever I find results relevant for VBScript, they aren't about how to do a custom sort, and whenever I find results relevant to custom sorting, they aren't applicable to VBScript, even if that was clearly specified in my search.

I would rather do this the right way, if that's possible.  If it's simply not possible to do a custom sort in VBScript, I can see a possible work-around, but it would add a lot of complexity and use a lot more memory than I think a custom sort would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you'd have to pass a System.Collections.IComparer to the .Sort method and that you can't create .NET objects in VBScript, the answer is no.

Comment: VBScript can create classes and use objects from .Net, so surely there must be a way. If the "List" is not inherent to VBScript and is created by means of: 

`dim list: Set list = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")`

But maybe it's because of other functionality lacking in VBScript - like the ability to use types and implement interfaces? (required by this VB.Net example: [VB.net Sort Arraylist By Objects Name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13608148/4993856))

Answer (score 1):

Regarding  work-around. You can make custom sort easily with JScript. Even being limited to WSH VBScript, you can instantiate `MSScriptControl.ScriptControl`, set it's language to JScript, create stuff that would be able to receive all the necessary data from file via VBS to the JS array, and then to sort with `arrayObj.sort( [sortFunction] )` using `function sortFunction(a, b){}` as comparer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
With rs
    .Fields.Append "SortKey", 201, 260 
    .Fields.Append "Txt", 201, 5000 
    .Open
    Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
        Lne = Inp.readline
        SortKey = Mid(Lne, Arg(3), Arg(4) - Arg(3))
        .AddNew
        .Fields("SortKey").value = SortKey
        .Fields("Txt").value = Lne
        .UpDate
    Loop
    If Arg(2) = "a" then SortColumn = "SortKey ASC"
    If Arg(2) = "d" then SortColumn = "SortKey DESC"
    .Sort = SortColumn
    Do While not .EOF
        Outp.writeline .Fields("Txt").Value
        .MoveNext
    Loop
End With
```

This is sorting a file using  a disconnected recordset.