# Append Format in VB Script

Tags: c#, vbscript

I am in the process of getting output just like below,

**Res: 10Test** from **Res:10 Test** using Append Format.

but when tried this below code,nothing happened and i am getting as **Res:10 Test**

Please let me know what is wrong with Append Format in my code and more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37928754/natural-sorting-using-vb-script)

```
dim arr
arr=Array("Res:10 Test","Res:80 Test","Res:30 Test")
Set oSB  = CreateObject( "System.Text.StringBuilder" )

for each inpt in arr
  Ispt=split(inpt," ")
  oSB.AppendFormat_2 "{0}{1,4}",Ispt(0),Ispt(1)
  Ispt=oSB.ToString()
next
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Split`() does not work as you imagined:

```
>> a = Split("Res:80 Test")
>> WScript.Echo "|" & Join(a, "|") & "|"
>>
|Res:80|Test|
```

So the .AppendFormat can't left pad the number 80. In [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37954803/603855) I made some effort to **check** the results of the `Split` and I demoed a RegExp approach that 'works' for cases (VBscript) `Split` can't handle (mixed separators).